# Styling text within script

Tags: javascript, css

I have a css and js id called `bob`.

The jQuery is:

```
 $('#bob').text('hello: ' + world + '%');
```

The css is:

```
# bob {
    width:280px;
    height:50px;
    border:1px solid #aaaaaa;
    border-radius:3px 3px 3px 3px;
    background-color:#dedede;
    position:relative;
}

# bob h3 {
    color: #444444;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:18px !important;
    line-height:24px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    margin: 10px 0 0 20px;
}
```

The issue I have is, the text hello world % should be in h3 tags. But it isn't!

Arrgghhh ... how do I wrap the text and style to pick up the css id.

Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put the content into H3 tags yourself, like this:

```
$('#bob').html('<h3>hello: ' + world + '%</h3>');
```

This will manually create the `<h3>` tag and style it appropriately. Note that I've also used the `html(...)` function, instead of the `text` function.

Comment: Ok so lets say I wanted to make the text WORLD BLU ?
I have in css .world {color:#3399ff;} how would I style the word WORLD, and so the entire text is h3. I realise I use SPAN, but I tried this: $('#bob').html('<h3>hello: ' + '<span class='makeblue'>world + '%</span></h3>');

Comment: You're very close, you just specified your css class wrong. If your CSS is `.world-text { color:#3399FF; }`, your Jquery could be: `$('#bob').html('<h3>hello: <span class="world-text">' + world + '%</span></h3>');`

Comment: thanks, thats perfect./.. I had tried so many methods lol, and was getting in a tizzy. Cheers Voted

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#bob').append('<h3>Hello: ' + world + '%</h3>');
```

The .text() call sets the text value of a node, which by definition cannot contain HTML. If you want to REPLACE the contents of #bob with your new h3, then use `.html()` instead of `.append()`.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answers, you need to change your css:

```
#bob {
```

and

```
#bob h3 {
```

Comment: #bob h3 refers to a h3 tag somewhere inside the tag with id=bob

Comment: I always do it like this #bob and #bob h3 , is that wrong then ?

Comment: There are spaces between the pound sign and element id.  You're right about the second one... it should be #bob h3